# fashion or clothing industry jargon for a pattern’s age range: toddler, child, adult

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a database of clothing items, I need to distinguish between those cut for 'girls' and those cut for 'women'. There are no offerings for 'toddler' or 'children', but this category would encompass them if there were.

What is a word for the categories infant,toddler,child,girl,woman?

I am using 'life stage' right now. But it invokes thoughts of insects or something; I don't like that.

Edit: Sorry, I was fishing a bit for words. The following are words I have tried and rejected.

Size describes small,medium and large. But a girl's size small is different from a woman's size small. So 'size' is not the term.

Age could be used, except it implies a numeric age.

Cut might be the term used in industry, I am not sure. I think cut refers to something like shorts vs boot-cut vs capri.

Comment: *Age range* or *age category*?

Answer (score 2):

The only example I've been able to find in an online shop is for gloves from a sporting goods store:
http://www.eastbay.com/Gloves/_-_/N-gz

They use Gender/Age:

- Men's
- Women's
- Boy's
- Girl's
- For Everyone

This makes me think that Age would be appropriate. I don't think that Age requires a numeral in this case.

Old Navy seems to call them Divisions
http://oldnavy.gap.com/

Cut and Size certainly don't work, I agree. Life Stage isn't bad, but you clearly dislike it, and I also don't like database headings with spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the Old Navy example. I didn't see 'Division' on the site, but they use it in the css classes, and, oddly, in text (Shop Divisions) that is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

- Department
- Generation
- (Age) range

Comment: Tut, as in Department OR Generation OR (Age) range

Comment: I am planning on using 'section_age' or just 'section', as in Girl's section and Women's section. Department is like that, a word a store might use. I am still hoping to find the word the fashion industry uses.

Comment: @BobbiBennett Please refer to my answer. The fashion industry does not have a standard word for this, perhaps you mean the clothing industry. We can look at examples in online stores, although they are divided. Division is commonly used in the retail industry, as they will have a Men's Division, Women's Division, Boy's Division, Girl's Division, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why "size" won't work, since you'd have different sizes within each of those categories (small infant, etc.) It does seem that the categories you're describing do correlate pretty well with "age", but that has some other connotations. And "cut" might be confusing.

What about something more abstract like "layout" or "configuration" ?